# Rails 3 : ActiveRecord select query optimisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails3 application in which I'm trying to optimise some SQL queries.

Is, `User.select([:id, name]).all`, faster than `User.all` ?

Comment: yes because User.select([:id, name]).all selects only id, name where as User.all selects all the columns

Comment: Ok but with the select, there is an additional method call and mysql have to search for the corresponding column.

Comment: @JérémyPouyet There is no additional call. `User.all` translates to `select * from users`, while `User.select([:id, name]).all` translates to `select id, name from users`

Comment: No. it's one query. 
@Catfish beat me to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `User.select([:id, :name]).all` is faster than User.all

1. `select id, name from users` is just faster than `select * from users`
2. All returned records are wrapped by AR so probably initializing object with only 2 values (id, name) will take less time.

   ```
   1.9.3p448 :002 > Benchmark.measure {User.select([:id, :name]).all }
   =>   0.340000   0.010000   0.350000 (  0.348017)

   1.9.3p448 :003 > Benchmark.measure {User.all }
   => 0.770000   0.060000   0.830000 (  0.935314)
   ```